# Javascript generated content not cached Ratchet v2.0.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, ratchet-2, ratchet-bootstrap

I am using the movies demo app app included with Ratchet as a template for my app.

The first thing I did was to change the static html movies on index page to jQuery ajax fetched movies. But the problem I ran into is that when I go back to the index page, it's empty because the javascript fetched and generated content wasn't cached.

This same issue appears here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/goratchet/3nlzW_A8Tys

The solution is to addEventListener("push") and cache the page, but I'm not clear on how to accomplish this.

- do I have to use Push to fetch content, and if so how?
- how do you cache the page?

Comment: took in ratchet.js https://raw.githubusercontent.com/twbs/ratchet/master/js/push.js

Comment: Using chrome dev tools I see Ratchet is actually caching the javascript generated content via cacheCurrentContent() in PUSH (), it's just not being used when navigating back to page and I get and empty index page.

Comment: @kindasimple i implemented your code from your answer into my ratchet.js file, but i don't know where i should use your last code snippet? should i use your last code snippet like <script>$(document).on('click', '#element', function(){ var e = CustomEvent('popstate'); ... });</script> in order to navigate back to a cached page?

Comment: Well, it doesn't matter where you put it, so that will work. The problem is that you aren't newing up a new object because you copied my code (that has a typo). create an event with `new` CustomEvent

Comment: @kindasimple thanks for your answer. problem is that when i navigate (with the code snippet) to the last page, it is not the cached version. `PUSH.id` and `PUSH.previousId` are also the same (when i `console.log` them). for example, i navigate from _page A_ to _page B_. on _page B_ i change the background color with jquery and a button, then i navigate back to _page A_ and back to _page B_ (with your code snippet), but the background of _page B_ is not changed anymore...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Push.js caches the context before you navigate away from the page, and caches it in the associative array `domCache` keyed by the timestamp for the navigation event. To go back to the cached page by firing a popstate event with the timestamp.

```
var e = new CustomEvent('popstate')
e.state = <cached-timetamp-key>
window.dispatchEvent(e)
```

The cached item key is the last item in the cached back stack `cacheMapping.cachedBackStack`

So, if you add a method to push.js (in your ratchet.js file) to return the next item in the backstack

```
var getPreviousId = function () {
    var backStack = JSON.parse(cacheMapping.cacheBackStack);
    return backStack.length > 0 ? backStack[backStack.length -1] : null;
}
```

and where save the previous id where the current id is saved e.g. find

```
PUSH.id = data.id;
```

and add the line to expose the previous id

```
PUSH.id = data.id;
PUSH.previousId = getPreviousId(); //save previous id
```

Then you can go back to the cached page with the following

```
var e = new CustomEvent('popstate');
e.state = PUSH.previousId;
window.dispatchEvent(e);
```

If you want ratchet to handle the automatically, you will have to go into the `touchend()` method or PUSH() itself call `popstate()` when its appropriate.

Comment: should i use your last code like `<script>$(document).on('click', '#element', function(){ var e = CustomEvent('popstate'); ... });</script>` in order to navigate back to a cached page?